# RegisterTouch Area saving Two Points

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing my first app in Andengine for the first time.Description of my project is:

1. 4 pieces are placed near to each other
2. move and place 4 pieces to 4 different plates
3. on a successful placement of 4 different pieces to 4 different plates, I generate 4 new pieces and then step(1) ,(2) and (3) continue.

Now I have implemented this scenario like this:

1. At initial i made new **BitmapTextureAtlas1** and **sprites1** and allocated specifics position
2. for new Object i made new BitmapTextureAtlas and assigned to previous **BitmapTextureAtlas1** and similar to sprites

3.I registerToucharea and atachchild  and then unregisterTouchArea and DeatachChild and Follow(1 and 2 and 3)

**Is this right Approach  to do It.**

**The problem I face is this:**

When i place pices1 To any plate ,It moves Successfully but their is some thing hidden at initial place of pices1 that when i again move from initial place of pice1 to any plate ..my flag increment that some object is moved

Comment: Hey,@Gulzar why you don't reply the post?

Answer (score 0):

From @GulZar question:

> Is this right Approach to do It?

Answer: No. You always load the resources(Graphics) before starting game play & it should only once.After finished the use of sprite you can call BitmapTextureAtlas.unload();

May be you think: Every time detaching a Sprite, You need to load Graphics again. Detaching a sprite is only cause to remove it from the scene, not from the memory.

You can create custom sprite class to use frankly. Example:

```
 public class Food extends PixelPerfectAnimatedSprite {

               public Food(float pX, float pY,
                PixelPerfectTiledTextureRegion pTiledTextureRegion,
                VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager) {

               super(pX, pY, pTiledTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);

        }
@Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
            float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttached() {
         super.onAttached();
    } 
}
```

Here, I extend **PixelPerfectAnimatedSprite** for pixel perfect collision. You can use **Sprite** or **AnimatedSprite**. Then you can override onAreaTouched,onAttached() and all overrides method from Entity. Now, Inside onAreaTouched() you write logic what happens in moving.

After Doing above, you can call it From your Game play Scene. When a player moves one pieces to a plate, then set a condition/Flag either new pieces would be attached or not. Depends on your logic. Explain more to get a good tweet.